# Currency Converter , In combo box values are being displayed but unable to scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am working on a simple currency converter.

The issue is when I run the app the values(Currency's) should be displayed in the `combo box` but its not getting displayed.

I am using the service reference for http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

pls help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use combobox control. Use the ListPicker Control.

Steps :

1. Download the nuget package from this link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit/
2. Add a reference to the top of your xaml file :

   ```
   xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
   ```
3. Use ListPicker as shown below :

   ```
   <toolkit:ListPicker  Height="50" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ConverterPage, Path=Locations}" Margin="179,129,70,434" Name="cmbCurrFrom">
           <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Location}"></TextBlock>
               </DataTemplate>
           </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
           <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Location}"></TextBlock>
               </DataTemplate>
           </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
       </toolkit:ListPicker>
   ```

Comment: Perhaps this works, but it's a bit like going to a shop and say: My bicycle doesn't work, and then the salesman says: Too bad, buy a motor cycle.

Comment: its giving error for listpicker, error is ,ListPicker doesnt exist in namspace toolkit

Comment: How can we add country names with the currency type